# Recording Waveform Signal into Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, labview

I'm currently trying to record the data of my voltage signal overtime, I'm having 3 signals (x,y,z) running at a time. I using random number generator in my attachment as example. I wan to record all 3 of my signal with respect to time and displayed in a excel spreadsheet when a button is clicked or the system stop. I want 3 of my signals and time to be displayed in seperate column on my excel file. Can anyone lend me a help on this...?

E.g. of my excel display outcome:

```
time | signal-x | signal-y | signal-z
```

Comment: If you give us code to debug, we'd be more able to help. I could only guess what your problem is and try to fix it based on what you have said so far.

Comment: You can download my attached vi here: https://decibel.ni.com/content/message/82522#82522
Run it and wait for while then press stop on the front panel.

Answer (score 0):

Excel does tab delimited documents, so:
[image]

Just name the file with a .txt extension and you've got it.

Comment: Ok, I tried it out with this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tqsBd.png But the result I get was same as before only.. The time and signal has been stack together in a single column.

Comment: Because you took my custom formatted string made to be saved to a file, and threw it through a ringer. Why are you saving using a premade VI which you don't know what it does or how to change it, when there is the "Write File" VI which only does what you want it to. "Write Waveform to File" will only save the Waveform how National Instruments wants it to be saved. If that means it can't do what you want, why use it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the LabVIEW function **Export Waveform To Spreadsheet File.vi**

http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvwave/export_wave_to_spreadsheet/

In LabVIEW context, a Spreadsheet File is not specifically an Excel file, but rather an ASCII file that uses a delimiter (default is TAB). Some people prefer CSV (comma separated) but that can be a problem if your localization uses a comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: yeah..i'm using it, but it doesn't work perfectly. I done it here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tqsBd.png I wonder where's the mistake?